# Converting double datatype column to binary and returning sum of digits in new column PySpark Dataframe

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, lambda, aggregate-functions

I am new to PySpark and I am trying to convert couple of columns with double datatype to binary and I want to count number of non-zero values in the binary number / get sum of binary number digits

My sample data looks as follows

```
bit_1   bit_2   bit_3   bit_4   bit_5   bit_6
0       2       8       0       0       0
11      0       16      64      0       0
10      0       0       0       256     144
12      15      15      0       0       0
20      0       17      0       0       0
250     12      0       0       0       0
300     72      84      64      0       0
320     100     120     140     220     240
```

so far I tried below

```
test_df = df.withColumn('bit_sum', sum(map(int,"{0:b}".format(F.col('bit_1')))))
```

above code throws me error

I even tried below

```
df_2 = (df
        
         .withColumn('bit_1_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_1')),12,'0'))
         .withColumn('bit_2_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_2')),12,'0'))
         .withColumn('bit_3_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_3')),12,'0'))
         .withColumn('bit_4_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_4')),12,'0'))
         .withColumn('bit_5_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_5')),12,'0'))
         .withColumn('bit_6_bi', F.lpad(F.bin(F.col('bit_6')),12,'0'))
    
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use [`bin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.bin.html) to convert the column values into binary string representation, then replace `0's` with empty string and count the length of resulting string to calculate number of `1's`

```
df.select(*[F.length(F.regexp_replace(F.bin(c), '0', '')).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```

---

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|bit_1|bit_2|bit_3|bit_4|bit_5|bit_6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|
|    3|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|
|    2|    0|    0|    0|    1|    2|
|    2|    4|    4|    0|    0|    0|
|    2|    0|    2|    0|    0|    0|
|    6|    2|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|    4|    2|    3|    1|    0|    0|
|    2|    3|    4|    3|    5|    4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```